# tomcat ExpiresFilter does not work

Tags: java, tomcat

The following is a snippet from the web.xml of my webapp

```
<filter>
   <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
   <filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>ExpiresByType text/css</param-name>
      <param-value>access plus 3 months</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>ExpiresByType text/html</param-name>
      <param-value>access plus 3 months</param-value>
   </init-param>
   <init-param>
      <param-name>ExpiresByType application/javascript</param-name>
      <param-value>access plus 3 months</param-value>
   </init-param>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
   <filter-name>ExpiresFilter</filter-name>
   <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>/dist/*</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>/lib/*</url-pattern>
   <url-pattern>/partials/*</url-pattern>
   <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
</filter-mapping>
```

When turning the logging.properties to FINER i get

> 2015 11:51:35 AM org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter
>   isEligibleToExpirationHeaderGeneration FINE: Request
>   "/kuku/dist/js/vendor.js.map" with response status "200"
>   content-type "null", expiration header already defined

I searched in the conf directory of tomcat

> grep -r expire conf

and did not find anything.

Where could the expiration header be set already?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it will help, but there actually two conditions under which you will get that log message:

- if the response already has an "Expires" header
- if the response has "Cache-control" header which specifies a "max-age" attribute.

Reference:

- https://code.google.com/p/xebia-france/source/browse/web/xebia-servlet-extras/trunk/src/main/java/fr/xebia/servlet/filter/ExpiresFilter.java?r=766

(I'm assuming I've found the correct source code ...)

Comment: I try to go in this direction. Is there a way to get a log of the life cycle of a request starting from the entry point and see the input and output of every part in the chain?

Comment: The problem was the BasicAuthenticator valve

Answer (score 1):

Update:
This is somehow connected to the security.

I had the following xml snippet for authentication.

When removing it the expires header was set properly.

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>All</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
        <http-method>GET</http-method>
        <http-method>POST</http-method>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>kuku<role-name>
    </auth-constraint>

    <user-data-constraint>
        <!-- transport-guarantee can be CONFIDENTIAL, INTEGRAL, or NONE -->
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
</login-config>
<security-role>
<role-name>kuku</role-name>
</security-role>
```

The valve can be configured to allow caching https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/valve.html#Basic_Authenticator_Valve

but it would be best to move away from this authentication scheme

Answer (score 0):

As stated by Stephen-C the `org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter` will not work if something has already set `Expires` or `Cache-Control: max-age` headers.

This answer is to provide a workaround to those who like to fix this and also to thos who really want to understand this.

Here is a workaround:

`public class MyExpiresFilter extends org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter {
    @Override
    protected boolean isEligibleToExpirationHeaderGeneration(
                      HttpServletRequest request, 
                      XHttpServletResponse response) {
        return true;
    }
}`
 
and update your `web.xml` with this class `MyExpiresFilter`

`<filter-class>org.apache.catalina.filters.ExpiresFilter</filter-class>`

and make sure your war containts this compiled code or web context has this class in classpath.

Answer (score 0):

I know it is an old question, but since I struggled with this recently, here is some more information:

The "problem" is in `org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase` which sets an `Expires` header for secured resources (which makes sense).
See e.g. (I only checked for Tomcat 7 and 8, but this is probably everywhere): https://github.com/Oreste-Luci/apache-tomcat-8.0.26-src/blob/master/java/org/apache/catalina/authenticator/AuthenticatorBase.java#L508-L518

The `ExpiresFilter` will not set header if the `Expires` header is present.

In my case I wanted to change the cache headers for a static resource, so I resorted to the meta HTML tag, more information at http://cristian.sulea.net/blog/disable-browser-caching-with-meta-html-tags/